# USB device not found intelliJ indea - Nexus 7

Tags: android, adb, nexus-7

ADB usb driver is installed i can see the nexus 7 with its friver just fine in My Computer - Manage section. And i have set the usb connection mode to PTP and intelliJ idea cant see my device

Comment: did you set Usb Debug Connection?